# Extend publishing in controller?

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, controller

I would like to extend the (un)publish-function in a sub controller.

I thought it would be enough to write something like that to my sub controller items.php:

```
    public function unpublish()
    {
        echo "Test";
        die;
    }
```

But on unpublishing my items nothing happens. What can I do here?

Comment: Have any feedback?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mark this as "solved". Your solution works great :-)

Comment: Maybe you can help me with an affiliated topic: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10814/call-controllers-publish-function-from-outside

Again: Thank you very much for your great support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [JControllerAdmin](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/legacy/controller/admin.php) what is used to extend your controller.

In `__construct` function on [line 62](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/legacy/controller/admin.php#L62) `unpublish` is set to use `publish` function. So there is no function like `unpublish`.

And in `publish` function you can get task name with `$task = $this->getTask();`.

Possible values are `publish`, `unpublish`, `archive`, `trash` and `report`. So you can compare, if it is `publish` or `unpublish` and make actions based on that.

Your function could look like this:

```
public function publish()
{
    $task = $this->getTask();

    // Do your custom actions
    if($task == 'unpublish'){
        // Do something on unpublishing item(s)
    }else if($task == 'publish'){
        // Do something on publishing item(s)
    }

    // Call parent function, so item(s) will get published/unpublished like they are used to
    parent::publish();
}
```